# How to get 10 last rows inserted in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I want to take just the **10 last rows** inserted to my gridview from sql server and to show them in my page.
This is my query:

```
SELECT Cause.Cause_name
       ,City.City_name
       ,InjuryScenario.InjuryScenario_id
       ,InjuryScenario.InjuryScenario_name
       ,InjuryScenario.InjuryDay
       ,InjuryScenario.InjuryMonth
       ,InjuryScenario.InjuryYear
       ,Place.Place_name
    FROM InjuryScenario
    INNER JOIN Cause
        ON InjuryScenario.Cause_id = Cause.Cause_id
    INNER JOIN PlaceDet
        ON InjuryScenario.InjuryScenario_id = PlaceDet.InjuryScenario_id
    INNER JOIN City
        ON PlaceDet.City_id = City.City_id
    INNER JOIN Place
        ON InjuryScenario.Place_id = Place.Place_id)
```

and this is my code in the aspx:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="InjuryScenario_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource30" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
     <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="InjuryScenario_id" HeaderText="InjuryScenario_id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="InjuryScenario_id"  />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="InjuryScenario_name" HeaderText="InjuryScenario_name" SortExpression="InjuryScenario_name" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Cause_name" HeaderText="Cause_name" SortExpression="Cause_name" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="City_name" HeaderText="City_name" SortExpression="City_name" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Place_name" HeaderText="Place_name" SortExpression="Place_name" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="InjuryDay" HeaderText="InjuryDay" SortExpression="InjuryDay" Visible="False"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="InjuryMonth" HeaderText="InjuryMonth" SortExpression="InjuryMonth" Visible="False"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="InjuryYear" HeaderText="InjuryYear" SortExpression="InjuryYear" Visible="False"/>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label runat="server"><%#(int)Eval("InjuryDay")+"/"+ Eval("InjuryMonth")+"/"+ Eval("InjuryYear") %></asp:Label>

     </ItemTemplate>

     </asp:TemplateField>

     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

here is the insert code:

```
DBManager db = new DBManager();
db.Insert("InjuryScenario", "InjuryScenario_id,"+"Cause_id," + "CauseType_id," + 
"CauseChar_id," + "Place_id," + "PlaceType_id," + "InjuryYear," + "InjuryMonth," + 
"InjuryDay," + "InjuryDate_id," + "InjuryInSchool," + "InjuryDesc," + "AlmostInjury," 
+ "InjuryComments," + "ProductInjury","'"+ num_id + "'" + Cause_nameDD.SelectedValue + 
"','" + CauseTypeDD.DataValueField + "','" + CauseCharDD.SelectedValue + "','" + 
PlaceDD.SelectedValue + "','" + PlaceTypeDD.SelectedValue + "','" + 
YearDD.SelectedValue + "','" + MonthDD.SelectedValue + "','" + DayDD.SelectedValue + 
"','" + InjuryDateDD.SelectedValue + "','" + InjuryInSchoolCBL.SelectedValue + "','" + 
InjuryDescTB.Text + "','" + AlmostInjuryTB.Text + "','" + InjuryCommentTB.Text + "','" 
+ ProductInjuryCBL.Text + "'");
```

Comment: In what order? Do you want to get just 10 random row?

Comment: in order of the last field date inserted

Comment: i edit my question and the insert code is in there

Comment: You NEED to look into Paramaterized SQL statements to protect yourself from SQL injection. [Look Here](http://www.veracode.com/security/sql-injection)

Comment: ok i will look at it.. but you have any idea why ir shows me only one row and not all of my rows? think that it is because of the sql injection?

Comment: You say it is currently only showing 1 row in your gridview? Have you tested your query in an SQL client to make sure the query is correct? You should try that so you can better isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see the insert statement and know how you are uniquely identifiying each case to help. 
I usually do things like this, have a unique ID for each new case as an auto-increment. This ID is used to enfore referential integrity across all tables.

Then to retireve the last ten cases I would just create a statement like

Select ...
From...
Where ID IN (
select CASE_IDS.ID from CASE_IDS
ORDER BY CASE_IDS.ID DESC WHERE ROWNUM < 11
)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm new in c# and in sql. can you tell me where to put this query?in the grid view? Select ... From... Where ID IN ( select CASE_IDS.ID from CASE_IDS ORDER BY CASE_IDS.ID DESC WHERE ROWNUM < 11 )

Comment: We cannot help you without knowing about your data model as I said in my answer. Do you have a unique ID for each cae stored in a table like this so that my method would work?